# How do I use proxy.py with ngrok

Tags: python, proxy, ngrok

I am trying to use proxy.py a python library which runs on my localhost:8899. The I tried to make the port live by using ngrok http 8899. Now I am trying to access the proxy url which is generated by ngrok as proixes in request. But am unable to fetch the response. The following are the step I followed

1. pip install proxy.py
2. run proxy command in terminal. The proxy is running on port 8899.
3. used ngrok and generated the following link http://0ebe-117-220-248-73.ngrok.io
4. 

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies={'http':'http://0ebe-117-220-248-73.ngrok.io'}).text
print(resp)
```

Tried to use it as proxy in requests lib.
But unable to hit the proxy

5. The following works fine

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies={'http':'http://localhost:8899'}).text
print(resp)
```

Is there any way to make port 8899 public so that I can use the proxy from another system

Comment: how do you run `ngrok`? Maybe it needs option to redirect to port `8899`  - like `ngrok http 8899`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't get any error when I run `ngrok http 8899` but I see any message in proxy when I use ngrok as proxy. There can be different problem: ngrok works as some kind of proxy and it doesn't tread you local proxy as another proxy but as destination page. It would need some method to use multi-proxy.